# custom mib for postgresql in SNMP Trap in python

Tags: snmp, pysnmp, mib, snmp-trap

i want to send snmp trap using pysnmp library for database(postgresql). like when database goes down send a trap, similarly for when database goes up send another trap.

so now  my question is how to define or create my own MIB file for the same in python.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may not absolutely require a MIB if all you want to do is to send SNMP TRAP. But I do not really know your requirements. Why do you think you need a MIB? Is it that you run some sort of NMS on the receiving side that requires MIB to analyse the event?

What you could do without MIB is to chose TRAP message contents that sufficiently describe the event using just OID-value pairs (e.g. required [TRAP message contents + possibly OID-value pairs](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/agent/ntforg/common-notifications.html#snmpv1-trap-with-defaults)), then have the receiver of the TRAP analyse it accordingly.

If you still need a MIB, then you could just create one in your text editor. Take one [of the existing MIBs](http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/) as an example. You may test-compile it with [mibdump.py](http://snmplabs.com/pysmi/mibdump.html) to catch possible syntax errors. Once you are done, [refer pysnmp to your TRAP object](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/agent/ntforg/common-notifications.html#snmpv2c-trap-via-notification-type) in the MIB so pysnmp which would compile and use it.

Comment: thanks for response, i have an application now what i have to do is to send trap to customer for example if my database goes down send a trap. so when i send enterprise specific trap with some status with specific oid then MIB must be available at the customer end or at snmp manager which can uderstand the meaning of the trap oid  or to map correctly.

Comment: In that case you probably should create a simple MIB defining `NOTIFICATION-TYPE` object with its own OID, description, relevant objects from this or other MIBs... You could use this MIB at both sides - pysnmp trap sender and your network management application (NMS).